# @Environment(\.presentationMode) reloads body many times in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swiftui

Set property wrapper to pop view "@Environment(.presentationMode) var presentationMode" but it is reloading view again and again. Why it is happening? any solution?

Comment: Why it upvoted?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Got solution and posted an answer :)

Answer (score 0):

What i have observed except @Environment(.presentationMode) we should use bool value binding with controller, Please check code:

```
struct newView: View {

@State private var isActiveView: Bool = false

var body: some View {
    VStack(alignment: .center) {
        
        NavigationLink(destination: PushedView(isActiveView: $isActiveView), isActive: $isActiveView) {
            Text("Create Account")
        }
    }
}
```

}

And on pushed screen check the code:

`struct PushedView: View {
@Binding var isActiveView: Bool

```
var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        VStack {
            Text(“Back”).onTapGesture {
                isActiveView = false   // to pop into previous view
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}
`

Comment: Checked with XCode13.1 and iOS 14,15